# Accepted methodology when using multiple Sqlite databases

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Question**

What is the accepted way of using multiple databases that record information about the same object that will ultimately end up living in one central database?

**Example**

There is one main SQL database about trees.

This database holds information about unique trees from all over the UK.

To collect the information a blank Sqlite database is created (with the same schema) and taken to the  tree on a phone.

The collected information is then stored in the Sqlite database until it is brought back to the main database, Where it is then transferred into the main database.

Now this works fine as long as there is only one Sqlite database out for any one tree at a time.

However, if two people wanted to collect different information for the same tree at the same time, when they both came back and attempted to transfer their data in to the main database, there would be collisions on their primary key constraints.

**ID Schemes (with example data)**

There is a tree table which has unique identifier called treeID

> **TreeID   -  TreeName           -  Location**
>
> 1001      -  Teddington Field  -  Plymouth

Branch table

> **BranchID  -   BranchName - TreeID**
> 1001-10001 - 1st Branch - 1001
>
> 1001-10002 - 2nd Branch -1001

Leave table

> **LeafID   -    LeafName   - BranchId**
> 1001-10001-1 - Bedroom   - 1001-10001
>
> 1001-10002-2 - Bathroom  - 1001-10001

**Possible ideas**

1. Assign each database 1000 unique ID's and then one they come back in as the ids have already been assigned the ids on each database won't collide.

**Downfall**

This isn't very dynamic and could fail if one database overruns on its preassigned ids.

***Is there another way to achieve the same flexibility but with out the downfall mentioned above?***

Comment: Well, for one thing, how are you going to uniquely identify a tree?  That's kind of a starting point to any further considerations.  Because if you can't resolve that accurately in 99%+ of the cases, you are going to have a pretty dirty duplicate dataset.  From your question, it almost sounds as if you have the tree ID beforehand.  Can you elaborate on your unique id schemes?  Clarification:  in terms of your business, not in terms of database.  Is is a precise gps location for example?

Comment: Regarding your possible idea: Does the id's matter that much? Can't the "central" db just create them as they are inserted, and if they're in some way needed to be in sync with the mobile databases post back the values.

Comment: @JLPeyret, each tree is given a unique four digit number. So it is possible to uniquely id each tree. Each tree is given an ID in the main database and the sqlite is created from that. I think the example of collecting info about trees was a bad one. I'll change the example and add more information.

Comment: well, honestly, i would worry more about the precise identification first, before worrying what to do with the data after.  now, if you *can* id the target objects (is it a real tree???) precisely, then, if 2 people come back with data for the same target, you can either a) "no, that's done already" or b) "let's update with your data".  the technical aspects aren't that hard, if you know your requirements **and** you have the ID issue licked.

Comment: The ID is not a problem. We can uniquely ID every Tree. It was more of if two blank databases go out and they both start with the same IDs what do you do with them when you get them back.

Comment: why not update the target with the data as it comes in?  i.e. if user1 says tree 501 is 16' tall and user2 says tree 501 is 17' tall, why not update the height from 16 to 17?  you need to look at insert vs. update handling, some databases have native support for update-if-exists, but there are tons of sqlite questions about that exact subject on SO already.

Comment: The data on both sets of databases are different.I want to keep both sets of data. The issue is because they both start at id number 1001, what to do with them when they come back.

Comment: then you probably need to add a source_id field corresponding to your source of info for both data sets and save that as well as in your master db.  at the end of the day, if you want to keep both sets of data, then you need an additional key field to store the data with.  i.e. (src01, 1001), (src02, 1001).  how you merge the data into 1001's info is up to you, but that supports 2 datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as an answer:

on the master db, store an extra id field identifying the source/collection database that the dataset was collected on, as well as the tree id.

(src01, 1001), (src02, 1001)

This also allows you to link back easily to the collection source of the information which is likely gonna be a future requirement.  Now, you may or may not want to autogenerate another sequence id key value on the master db's table (I wouldn't but that's because I am not that fond of surrogate keys), but I would definitely keep track of the source/treeid it was originally collected with in the field, separately of any master db unique key considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are talking about auto-generated IDs for related objects, not the IDs for the trees themselves.  Two different people collecting information about the same tree, starting from the same starting set, end up generating the same IDs independently.  The two sets of generated IDs cannot coexist in the same DB.

Since you want to keep *all* the new data.  One possible solution is to avoid using the field-generated IDs in the central database at all.  When each set of data comes in, take the data that were added in the field, and programmatically add them to the central DB in a way equivalent to how they are added in the field, letting the central DB autogenerate *its own* IDs.

This requires a mechanism to distinguish newly-collected data from old, but that might be as simple as a timestamp.